# Deleted Timeline from List, unable to restore?

Tags: list, timeline

I've deleted a project list's Timeline from my home page and I cant get it back

Answer (score 1):

The timeline on the Home Page of a projects site is actually the Task list view. You can edit the page, click on insert web part or add web part and from "App" select "Tasks" and click on add. By default, the Timeline is displayed. You can hide the timeline if you want to by editing the web part.